# Can `knitr` suppress execution or output in an sql chunk?

Tags: r, knitr

The document below runs the sql and shows the results.  I don't want any output to show up, either by not running the chunk, or by hiding the output.

Is there a way to do this?

````
---
output: html_document
---

## Hide SQL Output

First, set up a temporary database:

```{r}
library(RSQLite)
conn <- dbConnect(SQLite(), tempfile())
df <- data.frame(value = runif(1))
dbWriteTable(conn, "TestTable", df)
```

Now show a query, but try not to run it, and try
to hide the output.  Neither works:  it runs, and 
displays the table.

```{sql connection = conn,results="hide",eval=FALSE}
SELECT * FROM TestTable;
```
````

I get this output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround.  If I use the `mysql` engine instead of the `sql` engine, then at least `eval = FALSE` works:

````
```{mysql eval=FALSE}
SELECT * FROM TestTable;
```
````

will display the code with syntax highlighting but not execute anything.

I don't know if `results="hide"` is also supported, because I don't have mysql installed.

Comment: If you only want to display the SQL code, you can just use `'''sql` instead of `'''{sql}` (StackOverflow does not support literal backticks, so replace single quotes with backticks here). Only the latter is treated as R code chunks. The former is an ordinary code chunk in Markdown.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.  It doesn't work here (because I want to display the code on one page, and execute it without displaying on the next, without repeating all of it), but would solve a similar problem in many cases.  BTW, for others:  Yihui just accepted a pull request to add `eval=FALSE` and `results="hide"` to the supported options for the sql engine.

Comment: I see. That makes perfect sense. You are welcome to accept your own answer.