# Include an SQL code chunk into R script to be converted to a Markdown report

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to include an SQL code chunk into an RMarkdown report. I don't plan to actually run any SQL code in there, so the chunk will have `eval=FALSE`, eg:

````
```{sql, eval=FALSE}
select * from mtcars
where car = 'abc'
```
````

Now, I normally generate R Markdown reports using `rmarkdown::render` inside R scripts (as opposed to directly running `*.Rmd`) as described [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html). Is it possible to include an SQL code chunk into an R script to be converted to a Markdown report? Here is something I would naively use to achieve what I need:

```
#+ sql, eval=FALSE
select * from mtcars
where car = 'abc'
```

This is only needed to show a nicely highlighted code without running it, but rendering fails. I am getting  the following error:

> Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = TRUE) :    :88:15:
>   unexpected symbol

Seems like the only way to do so is to comment the SQL code out:

```
#+
# select * from mtcars
# where car = 'abc'
```

But I would like to have a properly highlighted code in my report. Is this possible in the setup I described?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40444521/109941

Comment: @JimG I think you didn't understand my question.I want to include an SQL code __into R script__ and compile it.

Comment: Compile SQL? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @JimG Generate a R Markdown report from an R script that has some SQL code to show

Comment: Not entirely sure what is happening for you, your code works for me with `rmarkdown::render` without commenting out.

Comment: Is the extension of the file you running `rmarkdown::render` on `Rmd` or `R`?

Comment: @slava-kohut it is `.R`

Comment: @Matt weird, I am also using `R`. I modified my post to include the error I am running into

Comment: Do you have a back tick or something else the line above your `#+ sql` line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199870/discussion-between-slava-kohut-and-matt).

Comment: Any inputs on downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of `rmarkdown`, your code worked fine without any changes. However, in more recent versions it is throwing the error you mentioned. One way, that works for me to get around it is to use a backtick before and after your query. Addtionally, setting `engine = 'sql'` will add formatting.

```
#+ sql, eval = FALSE,  engine = 'sql'
`SELECT * FROM mtcars
WHERE car = 'abc'`
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked out nicely. This might be a bug (or intended behavior for the reason we don't know).

Answer (score -1):

Per [@user2554330's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449065/109941), try the `mysql` keyword instead of the `sql` keyword.

````
```{mysql eval=FALSE}
select * from mtcars
where car = 'abc'
```
````

Reason:

- If you use the `mysql` keyword, the markdown engine will respect `eval=FALSE`.

Comment: This is useful, though irrelevant. My question was if it is possible to include SQL code into R scripts and compile with `rmarkdown::render`.

Comment: "Irrelevant" or just "annoying"? (I don't disagree with the latter.) (In the same linked answer, [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444521/can-knitr-suppress-execution-or-output-in-an-sql-chunk/40449065#comment68161726_40449065) is from the author of `knitr` suggesting the use of `\`\`\`sql` instead of `\`\`\`{sql eval=FALSE}`, perhaps you can use that. I'm not able to test at the moment, but his comment implies that it will not execute.)

Comment: @r2evans `sql` works fine for me even with `eval=FALSE` inside `Rmd` file. But again, this is not what I am inquiring about.

Comment: @JimG Would you please remove your answer because it does not address the issue?